# AFRAME - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: reactjs, redux, aframe

I'm using Aframe WebVr with react and redux. And I can't figure out how to solve it. Here is my open-source repo to this game: https://github.com/Nienormalny/labyrinth-game-react

[image]

You can find render function inside `render3D.component.js`.
And this happened only when Labyrinth is rendered and I will run vrMode (fullscreen).

It will be nice to get some help here. Maybe I do something wrong inside code?

Comment: It looks like an infinite loop somewhere (this will end with a `RangeError`).

Comment: I can't find the loop problem, because it work on the non vr mode. When i turn on vrmode it happened. I can't reproduce problem here

Comment: I've clicked the `glasses` and entered VR Mode but can't see any errors. Though you have a lot of unresolved warnings in console like: `Line 86:  React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'positionPlayer' and 'props'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`

Comment: This problem appear only in mobile firefox or if you run game with webvr devtool (chrome) or if you run the game in oculus browser.

Comment: In Chrome (latest) with WebVR enabled I dont see any errors, with WebXR enabled I see different error 
`Uncaught TypeError: navigator.xr.requestDevice is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (aframe-master.js:67695)
    at Object.173._process (aframe-master.js:67870)
    at s (aframe-master.js:38)` Sorry I wasnt able to help.

Comment: Reset to default on chrome://flags/ seems to be working